# CSS animation scale() not smooth

Tags: css, css-animations

I've encountered a small glitch in the CSS animation scale(). I've set up the CSS to scale an image 1.1 times when I hover the image. This happens correctly, but an annoying line goes over the image as well. This is due to the scale() transform, because if I leave this out, the lines do not show. Can this be because I make the image bigger than its actual size or ... ?

It's even showing in this fiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/gpafke6y/

```
transform: scale(1.1)
```

Image showing what I mean:

[image]

Comment: It's related both to transform and to clip. If you remove either it goes away. Seems a bug in Chrome

Comment: No longer happening in Chrome. But lines appear on Firefox.

Answer (score -2):

Use transition 0.5s that will be more smooth. See [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) or [here](https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/) for Details

Comment: It doesn't do anything about the lines, it's just faster but still disturbing.